# Slider navigation - next prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a JavaScript slider, which only works changing images automatically.  How can I add a previous and next button that works along with automatic loop, like normal slider navigation?

**This is the script:**

```
    function slider(sel, intr , i){
        var _slider = this;
        this.ind = i;
        this.selector = sel;
        this.slide = [];
        this.slide_active = 0;
        this.amount;
        this.intr = intr;
        this.selector.children().each(function(i){
            _slider.slide[i] = $(this);
            $(this).hide();
        })
        this.run();
    }
    slider.prototype.run = function(){
        var _s = this;
        this.slide[this.slide_active].fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeOut()
            _s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + 1) % _s.slide.length;
            _s.run();
        }, this.intr);
        var count = this.slide.length;
    }   

    var slides = [];

    $('.slider').each(function(i){
        slides[i] = new slider($(this) , 5000, i);
    });
```

**This is the markup:**

```
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="img/modal_slider.jpg" alt="modal_slider" width="782" height="529">
        <img src="img/modal_slider1.jpg" alt="modal_slider" width="782" height="529">
        <a class="slider_btn left" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
        <a class="slider_btn right" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider img{position:absolute};
```

Here is a fiddle of how it works right now: http://jsfiddle.net/barney/vbRLU/ (credits to [Barney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356541/barney))

Comment: use `var tId = setInterval(function() { ... ),millisecs);` so you an clearInterva(tId) before you slide to the next or prev

Comment: Do you want to keep the same slide or can it be slightly different?

Comment: well it depends... what are you changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted your fiddle with some new functions to permit the navigation using two buttons.
I hope that it is what you are expecting.

**UPDATED with embedded navigation buttons**

<kbd>[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbRLU/25/)</kbd>

```
<div class="small_box top_right slider">
    <img class="fittobox" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/854/592" alt="home10" />
    <img class="fittobox" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/435/392/sports" alt="home3" />
    <img class="fittobox" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/435/392/food" alt="home4" />
</div>

<style>
.slider img{
    display:none;
}
.fittobox {
    width:400px;
}
.next-arrow {
    right:10px;
}
.previous-arrow {
    left:10px;
}
.arrow {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:10px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0.8;
    color:white;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

function slider(sel, intr, i) {
    var _slider = this;
    this.ind = i;
    this.selector = sel;
    this.slide = [];
    this.slide_active = 0;
    this.amount;
    this.timer = null;
    this.selector.children('img').each(function (i) {
        _slider.slide[i] = $(this);
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //Display buttons and register events
    $(this.selector).hover(
    function () {
        $(this).append('<div id="previous-slider-' + i + '" class="previous-arrow arrow">Previous</div>');
        $(this).append('<div id="next-slider-' + i + '" class="next-arrow arrow">Next</div>');
        $('#next-slider-' + i).click(function () {
            _slider.next();
        });
        $('#previous-slider-' + i).click(function () {
            _slider.previous();
        });
    },
    function () {
        //Remove buttons and events
        $('.arrow').remove();
    });

    this.run();
}
slider.prototype.run = function () {
    this.next();
}
slider.prototype.next = function () {
    var _s = this;
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    _s.show(1);
    this.timer = setInterval(function () {
        _s.show(1);
    }, interval);
}
slider.prototype.previous = function () {
    var _s = this;
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    _s.show(-1);
    this.timer = setInterval(function () {
        _s.show(1);
    }, interval);
}
slider.prototype.show = function (shift) {
    var _s = this;
    _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeOut(300, function () {
        _s.slide_active = (_s.slide_active + shift < 0) ? _s.slide.length - 1 : (_s.slide_active + shift) % _s.slide.length;
        _s.slide[_s.slide_active].fadeIn(300);
    });
}

var slides = [];
var interval = 3000
$('.slider').each(function (i) {
    slides[i] = new slider($(this), interval, i);
});
```

Comment: it's perfect, thank you very much for your time! thanks for the embedded buttons also :)

Comment: one question @sdespont: is it possible that the arrows align depending on the width of the image? cause as you see if it has different widths the arrows still always at the same place looking kind of weird...

Comment: You could re-positioning as you want the arrows at the end of the `show` function depending on the new image displayed using CSS command. For example about the "next" button : `$('#next-slider-' + _s.ind).css('right','10px');` http://jsfiddle.net/vbRLU/29/

Comment: I have now an issue, if I click quick over the next/prev buttons it loads multiple images... how can I fix it?